# Getting information about the logical processors in windows XP SP0 (like GetLogicalProcessorInformation )

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-xp, windows-xp-sp3

I want to collect information about the logical processors in the system.

Preferably the exact same data as [GetLogicalProcessorInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function retrieves.

I'm using **Windows XP SP0**, but the function is supported only on **Windows XP SP3**.

I probably need some other 'similar' function.

Comment: There is no other similar function. If there was, there wouldn't have been a new one introduced in a Service Pack.

Comment: XP SP0 is no longer supported. XP SP3 is no longer supported either, for that matter. Stop using XP.

Comment: You can't decide for your clients what they can or can't use

Answer (score 1):

To determine number of logical processors in the Windoes XP SP0 system you may use [GetSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. dwNumberOfProcessors member of the [SYSTEM_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct contains number of logical processors.

For further reading I recommend nice answer by [Billy ONeal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82320/billy-oneal) in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566189/does-getsysteminfo-on-windows-always-return-the-number-of-logical-processors).

---

**Note: As pointed by Jonathan Potter, support for Windows XP has ended!**

---